# Awake iOS app in specific location

Tags: ios, background, location

I was looking for the most efficient implementation to trigger my iOS app in a previously known and specific location(s). As far as I could see, I could do this using some background fetches (taking advantage of the background fetches using location) and checking the current location (http://www.creativeworkline.com/2014/12/core-location-manager-ios-8-fetching-location-background/). However, it seems to be a little bit exhaustive for the battery..

Someone has a better idea??

Thank you ;)

Comment: Have you taken a look at *"geo fencing"*?

Comment: Look at the [Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010726) sample app.